# Replicate Google Maps Overlay Panel / Legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

The google maps javascript API has a very nice legend / panel that updates the middle point of the map based on click / touch events.  Nowhere in their documentation does it go into detail on how to create such a styled legend / overlay.

**Please see the example I am trying to replicate before you down vote the question, thanks!

Here is a link to the panel I am trying to replicate: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

(top right 'base maps' panel)

Is this the only way to do it?  Printing every line with content.push?  Seems dirty.

```
var legend = document.createElement('div');
    legend.id = 'legend';
    var content = [];
    content.push('<h3>Butterflies*</h3>');
    content.push('<p><div class="color red"></div>Battus</p>');
    content.push('<p><div class="color yellow"></div>Speyeria</p>');
    content.push('<p><div class="color green"></div>Papilio</p>');
    content.push('<p><div class="color blue"></div>Limenitis</p>');
    content.push('<p><div class="color purple"></div>Myscelia</p>');
    content.push('<p>*Data is fictional</p>');
    legend.innerHTML = content.join('');
    legend.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
```

Comment: Two down votes without reasoning.  thanks!

Comment: If you believe `content.push` is dirty, you could simply concat them into a single string yourself. `legend.innerHTML = "<h3>..." `

Comment: Why anyone would want to push or concat html through javascript is beyond me.   I ended up creating the HTML on page and then just using map.panTo. I'll include the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.  Just using html and css to style the box/legend and using the map.panTo to change the center lat and long.

```
<div id="panel" class="open visible">
                          <div class="mtam-title">
                            <a href="#" id="minimize"></a>
                            <div id="panel-title">Change Location</div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="panel-body">
                            <div>
                                <h2>Go Further</h2>
                                    <ul style="display: block;">
                                    <li><a id="north_america">North America</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="central_america">Central America</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="south_america">South America</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="australia">Australia</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="africa">Africa</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="asia">Asia</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="europe">Europe</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="middle_east">Middle East</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

and

```
//Pan to area
        jQuery("#panel-body").on("click", "li a", function (event) {
            var id = event.target.id;

            switch(id) {
                case 'central_america' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(18,-96);
                    break;
                case 'africa' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.0,24.25);
                    break;
                case 'north_america' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50,-100);
                    break;
                case 'asia' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.39,112.32);
                    break;
                case 'south_america' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33,-69.6);
                    break;
                case 'europe' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.69,14.67);
                    break;
                case 'australia' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.16,134.56);
                    break;
                case 'middle_east' :
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.19,45.26);
                    break;
                default:
                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.3,-99);
            }

            map.setZoom(4);
            map.panTo(laLatLng);
        });
```